# Mounting a hard drive without having the corresponding file system

Tags: linux, filesystems

I'm a veryyyy beginner please sorry for this question. I'm trying to understand file system and mounting.my question is to mount a hard drive did linux need to know already the file system?.I will make an example:if I removed vfat from linux so there is no file system like that and I want to mount a hard drive that vfat is he's file system can linux mount it.
I'm learning file system and I'm soo confused if u have some good materials please share it with me

Comment: The mount command is based on a system call, to execute code in the kernel: You need the support of the VFAT file system in the kernel (a Linux kernel configuration).

Answer (score 2):

You normally mount not drives but filesystems. In general a drive is partitioned and each partition is formatted with a specific file system.

To answer your question, in general you don't need to specify what type of file system you are mounting. Linux can detect the type from the file system metadata, except where there is no metadata and you need to use the "-t" parameter to say explicitly what type of filesystem you are mounting.

For vfat this call should be sufficient, if your VFAT filesystem is on /dev/sda1:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /my/mount/point
```